# res.send() creates TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

I know this error message has been asked before, but I don't believe other solutions work for me.

I'm trying to build a backend express server to handle API calls for a React app. I wrote a `getData()` function to do this, used by an `app.post()` to send it to the front-end.

The error only pops up when using res.send(), e.g. my API calls work, just break when sending.

Here's the relevant code:

```
const getData = async route => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        }
    }

    let corrRoute = route[0] == '/' ? route : '/' + route
    return await axios(`${URL}${corrRoute}?api_key=${API_KEY}`, config)
}


app.post('/api', async (req, res) => {
    let { route } = req.body
    res.send(await getData(route))
})
```

If I replace the `res.send` at the end there with `console.log` it prints out perfectly fine. The error is being produced in the server's index.js file, not in the React app.

Here is the full error text:

```
[server] (node:9680) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
[server]     --> starting at object with constructor 'ClientRequest'    
[server]     |     property 'socket' -> object with constructor 'TLSSocket'
[server]     --- property '_httpMessage' closes the circle
[server]     at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: you can''t send a `Promise` in response.

Comment: Am I sending a Promise? I thought the `await` ensured I would send the actual API data. When I `console.log(await getData(route))` it returns the correct data object, not something like `Promise <promise>`

Comment: `await getData(route).then(data => res.send(data))` produces the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Axios returns a lot more than just the data you want. It returns a response object, warts and all, which will get interpreted as such.
And you're sending that response object. It would be the same as res.send(res) (except for it being a different response object).

In order to get the actual data from Axios you'll need to change the following line:

```
return await axios(`${URL}${corrRoute}?api_key=${API_KEY}`, config)
```

to

```
const data = await axios(`${URL}${corrRoute}?api_key=${API_KEY}`, config);
return data.data;
```

Comment: Strange! I've worked with axios a few times before and somehow avoided this issue.
Your answer works.